# Git command equivalent

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone, git-checkout

is

```
git clone -b branch1 ssh://gitolite@host/project/testkit
```

equivalent to

```
git clone ssh://gitolite@host/project/testkit
cd testkit
git checkout branch1
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is supported by the [`git clone` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

> `-b <name>`
>
> > Instead of pointing the newly created HEAD to the branch pointed to by the cloned repository’s HEAD, point to `<name>` branch instead. In a non-bare repository, this is the branch that will be checked out.